# Adding edges to a graph in Boost.Graph

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I am trying to use the Boost.Graph Library to run Goldberg's Max-Flow Algorithm. Boost.Graph calls it [push_relabel_max_flow](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/push_relabel_max_flow.html).

However, I have a very hard time understanding the library and its type-system. The documentation, which I linked above, gives an example code. But in that example, the graph is read from a file. I want to generate the graph at runtime. This is the code I have so far (mostly copied from the example):

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list_traits<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS> Traits;
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, 
        boost::property<boost::vertex_name_t, std::string>, 
        boost::property<boost::edge_capacity_t, long, 
            boost::property<boost::edge_residual_capacity_t, long, 
                boost::property<boost::edge_reverse_t, Traits::edge_descriptor>>>> DirectedGraph;

DirectedGraph g;
Traits::vertex_descriptor s, t;


s = boost::add_vertex(g);
t = boost::add_vertex(g);
boost::add_vertex(g);
boost::add_vertex(g);
```

After I added 4 vertices to the graph I should "connect" them, i.e., making edges with a capacity, residual capacity and the reverse value. The function for this task is `boost::add_edge()` but I have no clue how I can pass my arguments. The example code does not show it, because as I said, the data is read from a file and then directly parsed to a graph. Maybe someone with experience in the Boost.Graph library can show me how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add an edge between vertices `s` and `t` like so:

```
boost::add_edge(s, t, {33, 44}, g);
```

Here setting `edge_capacity` to 33, and `edge_residual_capacity` to 44.

To actually access the edge properties, as far as I know you must do something like this:

```
std::cout << boost::get(boost::edge_capacity, g, boost::edge(s,t,g).first) << '\n';
```

which is annoying. It's easier if you use bundled properties instead, like so:

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list_traits<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS> Traits;

struct VertexProps {
    std::string name;
};

struct EdgeProps {
    long capacity;
    long residual_capacity;
    Traits::edge_descriptor reverse;
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
                              VertexProps, EdgeProps > DirectedGraph;
```

Then you can add vertices and edges just the same way, but it's easier to access edge properties, e.g.

```
auto e = boost::edge(s,t,g).first; // get the edge descriptor for an edge from s to t, if any
std::cout << g[e].capacity << '\n';
```

To add an edge between the anonymous third and fourth vertices you added, you can get away with

```
boost::add_edge(2, 3, {17, 26}, g);
```

since the underlying storage is `vector`, and so `vertex_descriptor` is just the vector index (aka `size_t`, aka `unsigned long` around here). But to be more strictly correct you should do

```
boost:add_edge(boost::vertex(2, g), boost::vertex(3, g), {17, 26}, g);
```

in order to get the `vertex_descriptor` for the 3rd and 4th vertices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! One last question: What about `boost::property<boost::edge_reverse_t, Traits::edge_descriptor>` ? Do I not have to give a value for it?

Comment: @Bobface: I left it uninitialized. For the first edge added, there's no reverse edge to put there! You can go back later and add it; if `e` is one edge and `er` is its reversed edge, using bundled properties,`g[e].reverse = er` will do the trick.

Comment: Could you maybe give me a short example how I can add an edge with `add_edge` and directly set the values (capacity, residual capacity,..) in the call when using bundled properties?

Comment: @Bobface: Just the same way. `boost::add_edge(s, t, {33, 44}, g);` If you have an edge descriptor `er` already, `boost::add_edge(s, t, {33, 44, er}, g);`

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't work. I copied your code and tried to run it but I get the following error:  `'DirectedGraph {aka boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, main()::VertexProps, main()::EdgeProps>}' is not derived from 'boost::directed_graph<VP, EP, GP>'
     boost::add_edge(s, t, {33, 44}, g);`

Comment: @Bobface: Works fine for me. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e35d1fa429fb1f6

Comment: Oh I see. I think it was because I copied VertexProps and EdgeProps into main(). When it is global it works!